# Javascript onclick function fails to fire

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm currently trying to create a small in browser todo list application using Vanilla Javascript as I want to get out of the framework mentality. I've written a very basic function that essentially outputs the value of a text field in an alert window when a button is clicked however for some reason I can't get it to work. I haven't done vanilla javscript for years so I must be missing something really stupid and I realise this is probably a really simple question but I'm at a loss to see what is wrong with this.

I have attached a fiddle containing all of my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/HD9A8/

As I mentioned I want to do this with Vanilla Javascript but I'm just having a complete mental block at the moment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
J
```

Comment: Please don't circumvent the requirement to include code in your question when linking to jsfiddle.

Comment: also, getElementsByName returns an array. So you would need to access it with ('title')[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the `onclick` function like so..

```
btn.onclick = addRecord;
```

For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Even when defining it like this, the code fails outside of jsfiddle. In Chrome I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: Right, move the addRecord function definition above the line where you assign it to your onclick property. You can also do `btn.onclick = function(){ ... }` and put in the code for your addRecord function in there.

Comment: I added a window.onload event instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with wiring up the event - I reviewed your fiddle with Chrome Dev Tools. Here's an approach I have followed in the past when developing vanilla js and not using a framework.

```
function addEvent(element, evnt, funct){
      if (element.attachEvent)
        return element.attachEvent('on'+evnt, funct);
     else
        return element.addEventListener(evnt, funct, false);
 };

 addEvent(document.getElementById('addRecord')
    , 'click'
    , addRecord
 );

 function addRecord(){
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    alert(title.value);
 }
```

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rnewsome/HD9A8/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a function to the button click (using an equals)

Try either of the following:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('addRecord');
btn.onclick = addRecord;

function addRecord(){
    var title = document.getElementsByName('title');
    alert(title.value);
}
```

which I've put at http://jsfiddle.net/HD9A8/2/

or

```
document.getElementById('addRecord').onclick = function(){
    var title = document.getElementsByName('title');
    alert(title.value);
}
```

which is at http://jsfiddle.net/HD9A8/3/

Comment: Even when defining it like this, the code fails outside of jsfiddle. In Chrome I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null